# How to define a task that is called for the root project only?

Tags: sbt

When I define a task it gets called for each project in a multi-project build:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import IO._

object EnsimePlugin extends Plugin {

  val ensime = TaskKey[Unit](
    "generateEnsime",
    "Generate the ENSIME configuration for this project")

  override val projectSettings = Seq(
    ensime := generateEnsime (
      (thisProject in Test).value,
      (update in Test).value
    )
  )

  private def generateEnsime(proj: ResolvedProject, update: UpdateReport): Unit = {
    println(s"called by ${proj.id}")
  }    
}
```

How can I define a task so that it is only called for the root project?

They are usually discouraged, but is this perhaps a valid use of a `Command`? e.g. like the [`sbt-idea`](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/blob/sbt-0.13/src/main/scala/org/sbtidea/SbtIdeaPlugin.scala#L47) plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official docs about [Aggregation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html#Aggregation):

> In the project doing the aggregating, the root project in this case,
>   you can control aggregation per-task.

It describes `aggregate` key scoped to a task with the value `false` as:

```
aggregate in update := false
```

Use commands for session processing that would otherwise require additional steps in a task. It doesn't necessarily mean it's harder in tasks, but my understanding of commands vs tasks is that the former are better suited for session manipulation. I might be wrong, though in your particular case commands are not needed whatsoever.

Comment: cool thanks. I think I'll continue coding this up as a command as we may wish to add command line arguments, and also the impossibly abstract API of `sbt` means that having access to the `State` is a useful thing in this case.

Comment: I'd doubt that command-line args preclude tasks from doing the work. My understanding tells me that you can execute tasks in similar vein as commands - I even think that there's no difference from end user's point of view. I might be mistaken...

Comment: BTW, could you show your solution to complete my answer, please?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking for. I'm using `Command` and that sidesteps the need to do any aggregation.

Comment: Are you implying that using a command means no aggregation by default?

Comment: as far as I can see. It takes `State` and (optionally) `args:List[String]` as parameters (unlike Tasks which can take arbitrary inputs).

Comment: Almost the same for `inputTask`s with the exception of no direct access to `state`. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I think Command is probably correct for my plugin: I am trying to create an alternative representation of the entire project so it makes sense to have access to `State`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246497 needs to mutate the project in fact (to a certain extent).

Comment: Yeah, commands aren't the right way to go here, generally.

Just turn off aggregation on your AutoPlugin or *only* enable it on the root project.

Comment: Option #2 is to put your task in `buildSettings`