# How to obtain the source and javadoc files?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am writing an SBT Command and I can obtain the full list of resolved files for any project with

```
import UpdateReport._
(update in Test).value.allFiles
```

However, this does not include the `-source` and `-javadoc` files.

How do I programmatically re-run `update` so that it resolves and provides me the sources and docs in an `UpdateReport`? (i.e. re-run as if `withSources` and `withJavadoc` were applied to every `ModuleID`)

Comment: Are you perhaps asking for `withSources()` and `withJavadoc()` as described in http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Download+Sources? Also please use `update in Test` as it gets clearer in reading (and I won't have to update the question :))

Comment: but you like updating my questions so much, I thought I'd have to leave you **something** to do :-P

Comment: I'm actually near to cracking this one on my own by understanding what is going on here https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/blob/sbt-0.13/src/main/scala/org/sbtidea/SbtIdeaModuleMapping.scala#L40

Answer (score 1):

ok, this was trivial:

```
import UpdateReport._
(updateClassifiers in Test).value.allFiles
```

Comment: You're doing very well with sbt! Congrats for having found the answer yourself! You may know it already, but if you don't, use `inspect test:updateClassifiers` to learn the value that the key holds. BTW, you don't need `import UpdateReport._`, right?